# Check for text value in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am having an xml as

```
<numbers>
<number>1</number>
<number>2</number>
<number>abc</number>
</numbers>
```

During serialization how can i identify that the element `<number>` is having **text** as **abc**. I need to allow only integers not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you understand on "to allow only intergers" the default behavior of the .net xml serialization could be enough for you. If the number member in your class is defined as `int` there will be an exception on deserialization your provided XML fragment:

```
[XmlRoot("numbers")]
public class Numbers
{
  [XmlElement("number")]
  public int[] Numbers;
}
```

If you want to have more control over the serialization process you can implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're stuck with is exactly what you're asking (and that the XML handling isn't an issue), you could use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) which will allow you to input a string and output the resulting number, if it is a number - the return value will indicate whether the parse was successful or not, and hence determining whether the original value was in fact a number.